# Align views with certain item on background image

Tags: android, android-layout

Let's say that I have  the follow image that I want to use for my background.
[image]

And let say that I want to have a text sitting in the middle of the RED circle. I want to do this in xml (and assuming  I want to use relative layout). Let's say I want to do it that way:

```
    <RelativeLayout android:width = "match_parent" android:height = "match_parent"
     android:background = "@drawable/background" >

    <Textview android:width = "wrap_content" android:height = "wrap_content" android:alignParentBottom = "true" android:alignParentRight = "true"
      android:margingBottom = "50dp" android:margingRight = "50dp"
      android:text="I am red" />

    </RelativeLayout >
```

If I use Nexus 4 then the text is perfectly in the center of the red circle.

If  I run it on larger screen then will the text be off? If so then how can a problem like this be fixed (where you align views and certain images on a background image) without having to do different layouts for every screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you suggest will not work to keep the text aligned in the circles. Since the `RelativeLayout` is `wrap_content`, the size of the layout will vary from device to device. As the width of a device increases (in dp), the center of the red circle, for example, will shift and not always be at the fixed location of 50dp from the right edge. For example, let say that a device is 200dp wide and the center if the red circle is 1/4 from the right side or 50dp. That works, but now let's imagine a device that is twice as wide at 400dp. The center of the circle is still 1/4 from the right side or 100dp. Your `TextView` has a fixed right margin of 50dp, so, relative to the center of the circle, the text will drift to the right on the larger device and to the left on a narrower device.

There are other ways to do what you want depending on the nature of your background. The most straightforward way is to make each circle the background of a `View`. That `View` can be a `TextView` in which you would use [gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:gravity) as follows to center the text:

```
android:gravity="center"
```

The circle can also be the background of a `ViewGroup` such as a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` but how you center the text may differ.

If your background is a single image that is square (as it appears to be) with the four circles and, assuming that the center of each circle is located as expected at (25%, 25%) from left and top for the top left circle and so forth until we reach the red circle which will be at (75%, 75%) then I suggest that you consider using `ConstraintLayout` (documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html)). The XML will look something like the following. Here I have placed text in the center of where the red circle would be and it will adjust according to screen size.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/vgdln2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/hgdln2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Red circle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/hgdln2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/vgdln2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/vgdln2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/hgdln2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Perfect . Thats the answer  I was looking for as I had no idea that we can use percentages using constraint layout. I wonder how this was achieved prior to the introduction of constraint layout ( you can see apps where they use background and views reference areas in them). I guess they were done in code

Answer (score 0):

Would using 4 `TextView`s and setting the circles as the background work for you?

Comment: Thanks but I I am using this example because I want to understand alignment and relationship between background and Textviews. MY point is it could be any background where I want to relate views to certain things in it

Answer (score 0):

Now this is possible using androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline. 
You can use 1 horizontal and one vertical guidline and give both of them percentage from top and from left of the screen respectively.

```
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline_top"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.65" />
```

The percatnage I have given is just a rough guess according to your situation. You can adjust it according to your situation.

And in your Text view you can do something like this

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="guidline_top"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/guideline_left"
    />
```